# Jquery .then not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an accordion, and want to trigger something when it has finished transitioning from one state to another. The following code is throwing up an error `Uncaught TypeError`, I am just trying to `console.log` when it has finished for now:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.accordion-tabs').each(function() {
        $(this).children('li').first().children('a').addClass('is-active').next().addClass('is-open').show();
    });
    $('.accordion-tabs').on('click', 'li > a.tab-link', function(event) {  
        if (!$(this).hasClass('is-active')) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var accordionTabs = $(this).closest('.accordion-tabs');
            accordionTabs.find('.is-open').removeClass('is-open').hide();

            $(this).next().toggleClass('is-open').toggle();
            accordionTabs.find('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
            $(this).addClass('is-active').then(
            function() {
                console.log( "Accordion Finished" );
            });        
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });  
});
```

Where am I going wrong? This is the first time I have used `.then`!

Comment: what do you think then() method is used for? https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Comment: how is transition done? Is there a css animation? What are you trying to do other than log to console?

Comment: can you tell us what the accordion library is? @mike-harrison

Comment: I mean if you ate using jquery-ui or bootstrap or something like that

Answer (score -1):

yes it's not working, this is not the way of using it  you need to learn `promises` first

It's used to replace (or provide an alternate way) the old callback mechanism with a cleaner way to handle asynchronous requests, instead of passing your callbacks as parameters, you can chain your function with .then, given function will be executed once the promise gets resolved.

Anyhow, this is just a basic explanation, you should really get into the books of promises for more info.

a simple example of :

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   if (true /* everything turned out fine */) {
    resolve("Stuff worked!");
  }
  else {
    reject(Error("It broke"));
  }
});


promise.then(function (x) { // Suppose promise returns "abc"
    console.log(x);
    return 123;
}).then(function (x){
    console.log(x);
}).then(function (x){
    console.log(x)
})
```

Comment: there is no promise needed here. All the code is synchronous. Just because OP used `then` doesn't mean they need a promise. How does this solve OP problem?

Comment: yes i know, i just want to him know about what is the root cause of his problem, and how use " .then" in future , and please run the code after remove ".then" might be help you to know there is no error in his code without promise block